# NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: not release memory useage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

Code like this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:10*1024*1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSData* archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[archiveData length]);
}
```

Set break point at in the for loop, it will see  the memory useage will increase as:10MB -> 20MB ....->100MB, when out of the for loop, it still not release memory.

Only when i continue the process(may be go into the next main loop), the memory useage will decrease 100MB.

PS:Turn on the ARC/Turn off the ARC and use keyword release is the same result.

Answer (score 2):

What you can see here is the `NSAutoreleasePool` at work. Just change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {  // new autorelase pool
        NSData* archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[archiveData length]);
    } // drain autorelease pool
}
```

This will result in a slower running time, but should tremendously reduce the memory impact.

All convenience constructors (nameing similar to `[MyClass myClassWithSomething]`) will always return objects that reside in the autorelease pool (because that's the contract with manual retain/release code).

The "default" autorelease pool does typically reside in the current `NSRunLoop` and will be released after each event handling cycle. If you create too many objects within one cycle, the pool will just grow and grow. So you can manually create an inner autorelease pool, which will then be drained more often.

Comment: I try to add ```@autoreleasepool```, it still not release memory immediately, my problem is the memory useage in the for loop is too big, i try add the code in for loop to ```dispatch_async```, it work but i do not like this solution.

Comment: It depends on what you do in your loop. The example you gave should immediately free the memory that `archivedDataWithRootObject` requested, so I cannot tell you more without knowing more of your code.

Comment: You are righ, the problem is memory in UIPastebord not release. i post another question, thank you.